# .NET File.Open() And File.WriteAsync()

Tags: .net, windows, file-io

Async File I/O can only occur if the CreateFile() API was called with the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED parameter.

However, when you open a file using File.Open, you provide no indication whether you're planning on doing synchronous or asynchronous I/O later on via WriteAsync().

So when File.Open() ends up calling CreateFile(), does it simply always include the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED parameter? Are there any negatives to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [File.Open](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,1a53662a82db3651) calls `new FileStream(path, mode, access, share);`. If you call [that constructor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,756b978acfa47bc7) that ends up passing `FileOptions.None` in to the `FileStream` which does not enable asynchronous mode.

If you want proper asynchronous API calls you need to call `FileStream` and be sure that the `FileOptions.Asynchronous` flag is set.

Comment: Woah. So all of my Await fs.WriteAsync() writes are not really being asynchronous? I need to go rewrite some code.

Comment: They are asynchronous, but they are not using asynchronous IO from the windows API.

Comment: So, what, it spins off another thread just to do the IO operation?

Comment: Yes, if you do not have `FileOptions.Asynchronous` then [`WriteAsync`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,646bf77f3c9e8556) will eventually call [`Stream.BeginWriteInternal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,fba94b8e653a1bab) which will create a [`ReadWriteTask`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,8c1732f39285c4cf) which is just a `Task<int>` and will, as you said, just spin up another thread to do the IO operation.